# Does Google Site Search have a advanced search option that could be added

Tags: drupal, google-search-api

Does Google Site Search Have the option to do an advanced search , if not is there anywhere online to show to add it in (this is for a drupal 7 site)

Thanks for any help on this

Link to the search option I am talking about.

http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products/gss.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know 2 modules for Drupal 7, if I remember correctly none of them offer a advanced search but here are the links:

GSS Mdoule is only for the paid version

[gss](https://www.drupal.org/project/gss)

And  google cse for the free(JS) version

[google cse](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_cse)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this , do you know to setup the gss module ?